# what's the difference between Modelobject.id and Modelobject_id in django?

Tags: python, django

want to know the difference between Modelobject.id and Modelobject_id in Python django.

Tried both and they both work the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They have the same return value, but have a different process.

- `Modelobject.id` re-fetching/hit the database.
- but `Modelobject_id` not re-fetching/hit the database.

For example, if you work with 2 models:

```
class User(models.Model):
    ...

class Product(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, ...)
```

So, if you come from the `Product` object, then you'll get the user id for example.

```
product_object = Product.objects.get(pk=1)
product_object.user.id  # <-- hit the database for querying the User
```

but if you come with:

```
product_object.user_id  # <-- this will not re-hit the database
```

> The other things is, `user_id` represented as a `user_id` field in the database of `Product` for relation purpose. Meanwhile, the `user.id` is represented as a `User(Object)` and `id(primary_key)` field.